# Quintic in $\mathbb{CP}^4$ with a single node

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity

Is there a degree $5$ homogeneous polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_0,\dots,x_4]$ such that $Z(f) \subset \mathbb{CP}^4$ is smooth apart from a single singular point, which is a node? (Node is another word for ordinary double point for me.)

The conifold $x_0^5+x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5+x_4^5-5x_0 x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4$ has $125$ nodes (e.g. Example 6.15 [here](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/joyce/theses/ChanDPhil.pdf)). The example here has $16$ nodes: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185333/resolving-nodes-of-a-quintic-cy-3-fold .

Comment: Take a cone over a smooth quintic surface in $\Bbb P^3$?

Comment: @TedShifrin: The cone has one singular point, but it is not a node.

Comment: Ah, of course. I wasn’t paying attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P \in \mathbb{P}^4$ be a point, let $X := \mathrm{Bl}_P(\mathbb{P}^4)$ be the blowup, let $E \subset X$ be its exceptional divisor, and let $H$ be the pullback to $X$ of the hyperplane class of $\mathbb{P}^4$. Then the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(5H - 2E)$ is globally generated, hence a general divisor $D \in |5H - 2E|$ is smooth by Bertini's theorem. Moreover, the map
$$
H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(5H - 2E)) \to 
H^0(E, \mathcal{O}_E(5H - 2E)) = 
H^0(\mathbb{P}^3, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(2))
$$
is surjective, therefore a general $D$ intersects $E$ along a smooth quadric surface, hence the image of $D$ in $\mathbb{P}^4$ has a single node at $P$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm missing some knowledge to apply it. How do I get a quintic polynomial from this? I don't know what sections of $\mathcal{O}(5G-2E)$ look like and how that would give me a quintic on $\mathbb{P}^4$.

Comment: And how do you get an equation of a smooth hypersurface from Bertini's Theorem? The argument I sketched is of similar nature.

Comment: I get an equation of a smooth hypersurface from Bertini's Theorem by taking a quintic with random coefficients. With probability $1$ it will be smooth, and I can verify this with the Jacobi criterion. Sadly, I don't see what's the analogue for $\mathcal{O}(5H-2E)$.

Comment: Assume that $P = (1,0,0,0,0)$. Take the equation in the form $$x_0^3(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2) + \sum_{d = 3}^5 x_0^{5-d}f_d(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4),$$ where $f_d$ are homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ with random coefficients.

Comment: Thanks! Here is an example: the polynomial `(x1^5+x2^5+x3^5+x4^5)+x0*(x1^4+x2^4+x3^4+x4^4)+x0^3*(x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+x4^2)` has a single node at $P$. Magma code verifying this:
`Q := Rationals();
A4<x0,x2,x3,x4> := AffineSpace(Q,4);
g := (1+x2^5+x3^5+x4^5)+x0*(1+x2^4+x3^4+x4^4)+x0^3*(1+x2^2+x3^2+x4^2);
E := Scheme(A4, g);
time IsNonsingular(E);` 
The code checks smoothness on the affine patch $U_1=\{x:x_1=1\}$. By symmetry, the variety is also smooth on the affine patches $U_2,U_3,U_4$. The only point not in one of the $U_i$ is $P$, where the variety is singular by construction.